# Assignment with pandas iloc where RHS length is shorter than LHS

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, mismatch

I am trying to perform `np.where` function on a dataframe starting from row 20 onward. The code that I entered as follow:

```
df['buy'] = np.where((df.iloc[20:,]['signal']==1), 'buy','no buy')
```

It showed the error below:
ValueError: Length of values (226) does not match length of index (246)

Anyone know how to fix it please?

I want pandas to return value from row 20 onward.

Comment: your main df contains length 246, the np.where you pass to it only contains 226, hence the error. For the 20 rows that you skipped, what value do you want to indicate?

Comment: So for the first 20 rows of `df['buy']`, do you want them to be assigned 0, 1, NaN or don't-care?

Comment: I intend to leave first 20 columns blank.

Answer (score 0):

This is an assignment error, `df` has 246 entries, but you are trying to assign a numpy vector with 226 values to it.

What do you intend the result should be?

you could subset the dataframe?

```
df_sub = df.iloc[20:].copy()
df_sub['buy']=np.where((df_sub.iloc['signal']==1), 'buy','no buy')
```

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for output buy or no buy from row 20 onward.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could use "mixed" indexing for the assignment:

```
n = df.columns.get_loc('buy')
df.iloc[20:, n] = np.where((df.iloc[20:,]['signal']==1), 'buy','no buy')
```